# Motion Manager is not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I am try to use motion manager in Swift but the log inside my update block never prints.

```
    var motionManager: CMMotionManager = CMMotionManager()
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01
    println(motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable) // print true
    println(motionManager.deviceMotionActive) // print false
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler:{
        deviceManager, error in
        println("Test") // no print
    })

    println(motionManager.deviceMotionActive) // print false
```

My Objective-C implementation works fine. Does anyone know why my update block isn't being called?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's because the motion manager instance is being thrown out when the method returns. You should make a property on your class to contain the motion manager. Additionally, it looks like you were only changing the manger's `accelerometerUpdateInterval` and then monitoring device motion changes. You should set the `deviceMotionUpdateInterval` property instead.

```
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { deviceManager, error in
            print("Test") // no print
        }

        print(motionManager.isDeviceMotionActive) // print false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought that all obj-c variables are optionals in swift (since they can be nil) so NSOperationQueue should take a bang thusly:

```
MotionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue!.currentQueue(),withHandler:{deviceManager,error in println("test")})
```

Apple documentation here :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/CMDeviceMotionHandler

States

The type of block callback for handling device-motion data.

Declaration
SWIFT
typealias CMDeviceMotionHandler = (CMDeviceMotion!, NSError!) -> Void